# Positioning list items with varied lengths

Tags: html, css

I have a ul list with thousands of li items. What happens is I have a Fixed width but Varied height li depending on the contents inside of them, such as comments, images, etc.

Right now my list flows horizontally through the user's screen and go to the new line. However, the problem is the first li of the next line does not sit next to the first li of the previously line but instead, it takes the longest li of the previous line and stays under it.

For example, http://oi47.tinypic.com/21kgqkw.jpg

can this be done ?

Update 1 per Chris's request:
Please look at my picture you would understand. Basically, all the lis need to stay close to each other vertically from lines to lines

Comment: Please show a sample of your HTML markup

Comment: Not sure what the problem is... What does your HTML and CSS look like, and what is the desired output?

Comment: look at my picture in the link please

Comment: Include some sample HTML, please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no simple way to implement a vertical flow like that in pure html / css, but there is a jquery plugin that does similar things. You should check out [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/)

Take a look at the [Basic Single Column Demo](http://masonry.desandro.com/demos/basic-single-column.html)

Answer (score 2):

Based on the limited information you've provided, the `li` tag **may not be** appropriate here. Instead, you could use `article` or `div`. If you DO use list items, a list of comments makes more sense as an `ol`, since the comments have a natural order (the date/time they were left).

The tags are not the issue here, just a note.

To the question at hand: based on your sample image [Masonry](http://vanilla-masonry.desandro.com/) may be your best route:

> Masonry is a dynamic grid layout script. Think of it as the flip-side
>   of CSS floats. Whereas floating arranges elements horizontally then
>   vertically, Masonry arranges elements vertically, positioning each
>   element in the next open spot in the grid. The result minimizes
>   vertical gaps between elements of varying height, just like a mason
>   fitting stones in a wall.

There is a [vanilla](http://vanilla-masonry.desandro.com/docs/intro.html) or [jQuery](http://masonry.desandro.com/) version of this plugin.

Comment: How could you tell what tag is appropriate with no content or context? What's "wrong" with a list being styled this way? Tag choice and presentation have no connection.

Comment: thank you so much for your quick and correct answer. You have my gratitude! Salute.

Comment: @WesleyMurch `li` tags are for ordered or unordered lists, and the limited info provided (text and sample image) do not indicate either use case. I don't know, because the question is vague. That's why my answer says "based on the limited information..."

Comment: My point is that the way you style HTML has no bearing on semantics or tag choice. There's no indication of what the content is, so saying that a list is not appropriate doesn't make sense.

Comment: @WesleyMurch - The question directly indicates the content of the `li` tags would be comments and images. That, combined with the image provided, does not indicate that the `li` tag is the semantically correct one to use.

Comment: It could be a list of comments...

Comment: Add your own answer then, sir.

Comment: Chris you may very well be right about a list being the wrong choice. It's common to hear people suggest HTML tags based on what the output should *look* like which is what I thought you were doing, and I wanted to make sure that misconception didn't make it's way into the OP's habits (or anyone else reading your answer). My apologies.

Comment: Personally, I would use `article` for the individual comments, wrapped in either an `aside` or `section`, depending on the use. There's not much information here.

Comment: Edited to clarify tag suggestion.